# UNWANTED PAGE BREAK WHEN THE REPORT_COUNT IS ONLY 1 JASPER REPORT

Tags: jasper-reports

Hi I have a subreport with a page break, how do I limit the printing of the page break when just REPORT_COUNT > 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
<break>
    <reportElement x="0" y="8" width="100" height="1">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}>1]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
</break>
```